# What is another way of representing x-=5?

Tags: java

Is there another way to code `x-=5` in Java? Thank you!

Comment: `x -= 1; x -= 1; x -= 1; x -= 1; x -= 1;`

Comment: Why exactly do you think you need another way?

Answer (score 3):

`X= X-5` is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

```
x = x + 5 * 3 - 16 + Math.sqrt( 4 ) - 6;
```

Comment: @brano88: I think with the amount of details in question, this answer is good!!!! who knows?

Comment: The answer is apropriate for the qustion.

Comment: @Nambari Please sir...He posted a stupid question, we could just downvote. And not to mock him.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try this:

```
 x = x - 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Its the same as

```
x = (type) (x - 5)
```

e.g.

```
byte x = 10;
x = (byte) (x - 5); // x -= 5;
```

without the cast it wouldn't compile.

---

An odder example of where casting matters

```
char ch = '0';
ch *= 1.1; // ch = '4';
```

same as

```
ch = (char) (ch * 1.1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming x is an int or another basic number type for which this operation makes sense:
   x = x - 5;

Answer (score 0):

```
y=-5;
x=x+y;
```

There are many ways

```
x=((x>>1)-2)<<1 + ((x/2)*2==x);
```